# What stat is used in the crafting room in fallout shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I just wanna know what stat I need if it's strength or agility I don't really know, so that's why I'm asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the item being crafted. Some items require strength, some require intelligence, etc.

That said, there are no restrictions on what you can and cannot craft, based on your dwellers SPECIAL stats. What this affects is how long it will take to craft the item. For example, when crafting an item that requires intelligence, dwellers with low intelligence will take longer than those with high intelligence.

Comment: Just a note that stats above 10 matters.  A rare weapon with 6 x 15 stat dweller is 46 minutes, but 6 x 17 stat dweller is less than 2 (TWO) minutes!